ImportError LIBSWSCALE_5 not found PySpin for FLIR Camera (Ubuntu 24.04)
I am trying to import PySpin to work with FLIR's camera on a Ubuntu 24.04 system
The steps I've taken:
I've installed Spinnaker from FLIR's website
I've downloaded FLIR's Python library
I have the correct Python version installed (3.10 as required), 3.12 came with 24.04
Installed latest version of FFMPEG
Installed latest version of libswscale-dev
Originally when trying to run python3.10 -c 'import PySpin' , I got various errors saying something like ImportError:libswscale.so.5 not found or ImportError:libavutil.so.56 not found
To try to fix this error, I tried
sudo find /lib -iname libswscale*
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -sv libswscale.so.7 libswscale.so.5 

Those errors are gone, not sure if what I did fixed it. However, now there are now errors saying when I try to run PySpin:
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.5: version `LIBSWSCALE_5' not found (required by /opt/spinnaker/lib/libSpinVideo.so.4)


Could someone please give me some directions to solve this problem? Is there a missing package I need to download? Do I need to downgrade these libraries to past versions to be compatible with what Spinnaker is asking for? Thanks!

Same issue here, did you find any workaround?

@Oliver Yes, in the end I reverted back to Ubuntu 22.04 and there were no more issues. Guessing the software hasn't been updated to be compatible with 24.04. Let me know if you need any help!
